# How do I sync only "My Contacts" from Google on Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s, sync

Is there any way that I can limit my Galaxy S to only download & sync contacts from the google account that are in "My Contacts"? Right now, it downloads everything, in particular, contacts in the "Other Contacts" group which has people that I've only emailed one time (or responded to). This takes my contact list from <200 up to 500+. On the other side, any way to use the groups that I've included in my google account?

I'm not opposed to using a separate application to manage these. It seems to me that Samsung's contact implementation is just poorly thought out, and I really hope that they make drastic changes to it for the 2.2 update.

Answer (score 11):

`Contacts | Menu | Display Options | Choose contacts to display (account)`

Make sure only "System Group: My Contacts" is checked. Or whichever groups you actually want to see. (More specifically, make sure "All other contacts" is **not** checked.)

Comment: Unfortunatly, that option isn't there. This is all that I see:
http://imgur.com/Miq13.jpg

Comment: Oh well. Such is the downside of allowing carriers to make their own modifications to the OS. Checking the "only contacts with phones" option might help, because if they're really people you've only e-mailed once or twice, it's unlikely that you have a phone number for them.

Comment: This does now appear in the Galaxy S Froyo release, I see `Contacts | Menu (More) | Display Options | Choose contacts to display (account) | System Group: My Contacts`

Comment: <Great Answer badge> I have a hundreds of contacts in both my personal and work accounts (GMail and Google Apps). It's nearly 30 years of contacts from college, grad school, work, etc. Lots of people that I exchange Christmas cards with or send email to, but never call.  Now, I have a group for each contact list called "Sync to Phone" and only display those. From 800+ items to about 150 that I actually talk to on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

al-e is right, but keep in mind that the menu changes depending on which tab/icon you have selected. Be sure that the "contacts" icon is selected from within the contacts app.  Here are the steps I used for the Galaxy S4, including the step if you have multiple gmail accounts.

1. Open contacts app
2. Be sure contacts tab is selected at the top
3. Hit the menu button and select "contacts to display"
4. Press the "customized list" gear button
5. Select the dropdown for the email acct that you are synchronizing
6. Uncheck everything but "My contacts"

Answer (score 0):

**Filtering Contacts** : You can filter contacts from particular group.

```
Contacts | Click - Menu Button | Filter | Click - Google (account) | Select - System Group: My Contacts
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [Groupy](http://www.appbrain.com/app/groupy-no-ads/com.kigate.groupynoads)

Comment: @Matt Link only answer... you can do better than that ;)