# Sync only Gmail "My Contacts" group on android 2.3

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail, motorola-atrix-4g

I have more then 2k contacts on other contacts, but i only want to sync the  "my contacts".

Any hints?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/sync-only-my-contacts-from-google-on-samsung-galaxy-s

Comment: Not a duplicate.  MotoBLUR has its own contacts app that doesn't have the same options.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot select which contacts to sync, but you can limit which groups are visible in the Contacts/Dialer apps:

1. In the Contacts app go to `Menu -> Display options`.
2. Under the "Choose contacts to display" section, tap on the arrow next to your Gmail account to expand it.
3. Uncheck all groups except "System Group: My Contacts" and tap the "Done" button.

Now only the selected contacts should be displayed.

*[Edit]*
Found the official Motorola video on Youtube talking about their Contacts app.  At the [1:00 mark](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Zq48ZOM8EM8#t=61s) they start talking about managing groups. It sounds like you should be able to create a new group and assign your contacts there, and then select to display only that particular group.  Give that a shot.

Comment: Didn't work,  in my contacts app, after menu, i only have:

Add Contact, Search, Display Groups, My Info, Manage accounts, more  (Settings, share name cards, import/export)

In any of these options, i found the choose contacts do display options.

Comment: I was listing the options of stock Android 2.3 Contacts app.  Sounds like your Atrix is running a Motorola's own Contacts app (BLUR?) Have you tried looking in the "Display Groups" option?

Comment: yea, i tried, but isn't there.

You know any way to remove BLUR?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Zq48ZOM8EM8#t=61s this is the official Motorola video. Looks like you need to create a Display Group, assign some contacts to it, and then you should be able to display only that group.