# How to limit the synchronized contacts to "My Contacts" on a Galaxy Note?

Tags: bluetooth, google-account, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have a problem with my Galaxy Note II (Android 4.1.1) when synchronizing the contacts I have on the phone via Bluetooth with my car. I believe this is some limitation of the number of contacts (or groups of contacts) I have on my phone. The same problem is present on my wife's Galaxy S3.

I therefore would like to understand how the Galaxy Note II synchronizes its contacts with Google. I keep all my contacts in Google (I have nothing locally) and would like to just get the *"My Contacts"* group (with the hope it will fix the Bluetooth synchronization problem).

I tried to limit the accounts [as explained in another post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/how-do-i-sync-only-my-contacts-from-google-on-samsung-galaxy-s) but even though the title of the post is the same as mine, the solutions seem to only limit the number of **displayed** contacts.

What I did was to:

1. stop the synchronization for the google account (for contacts)
2. forcefully delete all contacts from my phone (with [Mass Contacts Delete](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.probosoft.masscontactsdelete), [Delete All Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.DeleteAllContacts) and [Delete Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.umobile.delall)
3. choose only *"My Contacts"* in `Contacts | Menu | Display Options | Choose contacts to display (account)`
4. restart the synchronization

I end up with all google contacts synchronized again (*"My Contacts"*, the groups within and the *"Other Contacts"* one). I know this because when running the batch contact delete apps they inform me that 500+ contacts will be deleted (while I should have only 30 or so synchronized).

This is why I suspect the solution given in the post I mentioned (and which I basically run in the points 2-4 above) just helps to limit the display (and not the whole synchronization).

I would be grateful for

- some general information about how the Google accounts are synchronized with Android (specifically Samsung Galaxy)
- possibly a way to limit the "visible" accounts, as presented by the phone via Bluetooth (the idea being that even if the phone has all the contacts synchronized, maybe there is a way to set it up so that it "presents" (makes visible to other devices) only a subset).

Note: the inferior alternative OS :) (iOS) worked as expected out of the box -- so I guess this is something which is manageable in Android as well.

Comment: If you provide the links in comments or chat, I will add them.

Comment: Also, this isn't a forum ;)

Comment: @Liam W: Thanks, here are tghe links:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.DeleteAllContacts and https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.umobile.delall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4.2.2 and 4.3 customized ROMs ([CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) in my case) fix the issue

... and bring in other ones, less important (the mp3 tags are not streamed with the musioc for instance = the name of the song is not displayed).

Answer (score 0):

After having tried anything I could think of and all the solutions in various group the only one which works was to use [Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp) to forcefully transfer the contacts I wanted to have on my car system.

This is not an optimal solution as

- the contacts are just transferred, not synchronized
- new contacts on my phone need to be transferred manually

but at least this gives me something similar to what I had with an iPhone, out of the box (all contacts transferred and synchronized, as expected)