# Different contacts on multiple phones with the same google account?

Tags: contacts, google-account

I own two lines (different carriers), and one of them is currently on my Galaxy S4. I am thinking of purchasing another (open) android device to place the other SIM on. Since I have purchased apps from the Play Store, I wish to install them on the new android device as well.

Obviously, I have different contacts on each phones and I want to keep it that way. Will it be possible to have different sets of contacts under one google account?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there are at least two ways to achieve this:

- **use a different Google Account**
  the most obvious variant. But probably not working for you, as you cannot transfer your payed apps to it
- **make use of contact groups**
  create appropriate groups using GMail's web interface, splitting your contacts in your preferred way. Then on each device, select to only *show* the corresponding group. (see also [How do I sync only “My Contacts” from Google on Samsung Galaxy S?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2472/16575) and the questions in its "Linked" section). Though in this case *all contacts are synced to both devices,* you can chose to only show the preferred group on each.